# Sending file to computer via bluetooth results in "connection failed" error

Tags: troubleshooting, bluetooth, arch-linux, file-transfer

This was working fine a weeks ago, but now when I try to send a file to my computer from my phone via bluetooth, it results in "Connection failed." I noticed that if I look in the GNOME Bluetooth settings, the status will keep going from "Connected" to "Disconnected" and back again. This is also evidenced by `bluetoothctl`.

```
$ bluetoothctl
[NEW] Controller 00:02:5B:11:04:D8 BlueZ 5.18 [default]
[NEW] Device 24:C6:96:16:49:37 Drew
[bluetooth]# connect 24:C6:96:16:49:37
Attempting to connect to 24:C6:96:16:49:37
[CHG] Device 24:C6:96:16:49:37 Connected: yes
Connection successful
[CHG] Device 24:C6:96:16:49:37 Connected: no
[CHG] Device 24:C6:96:16:49:37 Connected: yes
[CHG] Device 24:C6:96:16:49:37 Connected: no
[CHG] Device 24:C6:96:16:49:37 Connected: yes
[CHG] Device 24:C6:96:16:49:37 Connected: no
[CHG] Device 24:C6:96:16:49:37 Connected: yes
[CHG] Device 24:C6:96:16:49:37 Connected: no
[CHG] Device 24:C6:96:16:49:37 Connected: yes
[CHG] Device 24:C6:96:16:49:37 Connected: no
```

The weird thing is that transferring a file from the computer to the phone is working fine. Restarting the phone, and re-pairing has made no difference.

Comment: Posting this and the answer in case I run into the problem again.

Answer (score 0):

Running this command resolved the problem.

```
# hciconfig hci0 up
```

Even though, the device `hci0` displayed an `UP` status when running `hciconfig`, this still fixed the problem for some reason.

The idea to try this came from https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=172261

Comment: I still get bluetooth file not send, though the connection goes up and down.  This was on Debian Jessie.